# How to generate Google Search result's time line image

Tags: java

Can you please tell me if there is any open source library which generate 'timeline image' in Google Search result? (see below as an example):

http://www.google.com/search?q=history&hl=en&sa=X&tbo=1&tbs=tl:1,tll:1400,tlh:1599&ei=oL46SsOrIIy0sgPQrrCDCw&oi=timeline_histogram_nav&ct=timeline-histogram&cd=9

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That image is generated by  [Google Chart Server](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). You can use this from your web applications. I'm not aware of an open source equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

These graphs are similar to sparklines which were based on thoughts by [Edward Tufte](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0001OR).

There's quite a few open source libraries which can generate these, including JQuery. You can find more implementation links by searching Google for "sparkline [language]".